# grails <g:select> drop down unable to display correct value

Tags: grails

This drop down almost works the way I want it too. I'm unable to display the `body` property or the `toString` of an answer object.

```
<g:select name="questionId"
        from="${questionInstance.answers.id}"
        value="${questionInstance.correctAnswer.id}"
        noSelection="['':'Select a Module']" />
```

[image: dropdown image]

unfortunately, no matter what combination I try, I can not get the drop down to, by default, select the `correctAnswer` without using the `id` in the `from` attribute.

```
<g:select name="questionId"
        from="${questionInstance.answers}"
        value="${questionInstance.correctAnswer}"
        noSelection="['':'Select a Module']" />
```

[image: second image]

what am I doing wrong?

## question

```
class Question {

    DateTime dateCreated
    DateTime lastUpdated

    String body
    Answer correctAnswer
    Integer ordinal

    static belongsTo = [lesson: Lesson]
    static hasMany = [answers: Answer]

    static constraints = {
        body blank: false
        correctAnswer nullable: true,
                validator: { Answer val, Question obj ->
                // Correct answer must have this as it's question
                val ? val.question == obj : true // TODO: Give this a proper error message
            }
        ordinal unique: 'lesson'
    }

    static mapping = {
        lesson lazy: false
        answers sort: 'ordinal'
    }
}
```

## answer

```
class Answer {

    DateTime dateCreated
    DateTime lastUpdated

    String body
    Integer ordinal
    String reason

    static belongsTo = [question: Question]

    static constraints = {
        body blank: false
        ordinal unique: 'question'
        reason blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        question lazy: false
    }

    String toString() {
        "Answer: $body"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say, this should work:

```
<g:select name="questionId"
    from="${questionInstance.answers}"
    value="${questionInstance.correctAnswer}"
    optionKey="id"
    optionValue="body"
    noSelection="['':'Select a Module']" />
```

Comment: running into the issue of nothing being selected. I don't understand why because `questionInstance.correctAnswer` and the first item in the `questionInstance.answers` are the same

Comment: try implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()` to ensure equality on id in the `Question` class

Comment: I've added the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation to the questions domain and everythign works fine! Do you know why it was necessary to do that?

Comment: adding an `optionKey="id"` will cause the drop down to unselect the correct answer on page load. Such a weird behavior

Comment: the default equality methods do not take the id into account.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the domains Questions and Answer?

In the meanwhile try adding attributes optionKey="id" optionValue="name"

provided the Domains have a name property.

Comment: I can use option key and value but only if I remove the `id` from the `from="${questionInstance.answers.id}"` which prevents the correct answer from being selected by default

Comment: I will try to simulate it in my system and let you know.